# Angular getter and setter behaviour difference in post request json

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

This is an Angular 9 + ASP.NET Core 3.1 application.
This is the model I use and my issue relies on.

```
export class HeadingModel {
id: number;

private colourVal: string;
public get colour() {
    //code
}
public set colour(value) {
    //code
}
.
.
.etc
```

}

On the left, you see the JSON request body of a post request to create an entity on the backend.
On the right, you see the JSON request body of a put request to update an entity on the backend.
(So I send a get request, make some changes to the received model and send it back)

My question is 
But on the create request angular uses my private var name instead of using the getter's name. (colourVal)

But on the post request, it uses the getter's name, which is correct.

Why different behaviors? how do I fix it?

[image]

There are my component code

```
createHeading(): void {
this.requestManagerService.create
  (this.headingWrapperModel, '/iot/Headings/Add').subscribe(
    (res) => {
      if (res) {
        this.toastrService.success('Heading created successfully', '', {
          disableTimeOut: false,
        });
        this.resetForm();
        this.showSpinner = false;
      } else {
        this.toastrService.error('An error occurred while creating the heading.', '', {
          disableTimeOut: false,
        });
      }
    },
    (error) => {
      console.error();
      this.showSpinner = false;
      this.toastrService.error(
        'An error occurred while creating the heading. Please contact administrator.',
        '',
        { disableTimeOut: false }
      );
    }
  );
```

}

```
updateHeading(): void {
    this.requestManagerService.update
      (this.headingWrapperModel, '/iot/Headings/Update').subscribe(
        (res) => {
          if (res) {
            this.toastrService.success('Heading updated successfully', '', {
              disableTimeOut: false,
            });
            this.resetForm();
            this.showSpinner = false;
          } else {
            this.toastrService.error('An error occurred while updating the heading.', '', {
              disableTimeOut: false,
            });
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error();
          this.showSpinner = false;
          this.toastrService.error(
            'An error occurred while updating the heading. Please contact administrator.',
            '',
            { disableTimeOut: false }
          );
        }
      );
  }
```

This is my service code

```
public create<T>(item: T, endpoint: string): Observable<T> {
return this.httpClient.post<T>(environment.boardpacAPIURL + endpoint, item).pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError<T>('RestApiHttpService')));
```

}

```
public update<T>(item: T, endpoint: string): Observable<T> {
return this.httpClient.put<T>(environment.boardpacAPIURL + endpoint, item).pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError<T>('RestApiHttpService')));
```

}

Comment: @R. Richard if you send a post request with a model which has getter and setter you can reproduce it. No further debugging info is required.

Comment: At least give us the code the post is actually called.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with more details. I hope this helps you to assist me. Thank you very much.

Comment: What i can say for sure it that the bug is not in the posted code and you'll have to look into where ever `this.headingWrapperModel` is being set.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are not sending the same object. In the case of the Update, you might overwrite your object with the result of the query, so this object has no getters or setters, is the result of the get Request.

When you are changing the values, you are not changing directly the property.

In the case of the post, you still has the object that has getters and setters, and when you are assigning a value you are feeding the _varible.